# std::list of executable functions?

Tags: c++, list, function, stdlist

I'm trying to write a program that simulates a simple system. The user adds blocks that modify the signal and the program "runs the signal through the blocks". I want to write it so it simulates a real system and I'm working on this solution but don't really know how to do it:
I have multiple "blocks" functions in my signal class that look like this for example:

```
float sygnal::Wzmocnienie(float p, float q){
        p=p*q;
        return p;
}
```

This is for amplification for example. It takes the value and amplifies it by a value passed to the function. Now what I'm trying to do, is make a function that first adds proper functions to a std::list like this:

```
list<float> OpcjeProgramu(list<float> opcje, int argc, char *argv[], sygnal syg){
    double p=0;
    typedef float(sygnal::*funkcja)(float,float);
    funkcja f;
    for(int i=0; i<argc; i++){
        if(strcmp(argv[i],"-G")==0){
                f=&sygnal::Potegowanie;
                opcje.push_back((syg.*f)(syg.u,0));
            }
```

And then a function that executes all the blocks in two loops like this:(rozmiar means the amount of numbers it has to modify)

```
for(int j=1; j<rozmiar; j+=2){
            u=dane[j];
            for(i=lista.begin(); i!=lista.end(); i++){
                //function to modify signal should be here
            }
        }
```

I don't really know how to make a list of functions and then how to call those functions - I made a list of floats and realised it only returns the values and doesn't execute the functions when I need them to.

Comment: Do all of these "functions" have the same arguments?, for example, is the signature always `float(float,float)`

Comment: This: `float (Func*)(float,float) = someFuncName;` creates a [function pointer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_pointer), this is probably what you need

Comment: Yes, all these functions take the same arguments. I know how to make a function pointer, but the harder part is to make a list containing them. How do I go about doing that?

Comment: Try `std::function`.

Comment: Or do `typedef float (func_t*)(float,float);` and then later you can do this: `std::vector<func_t> myVect;` or whatever suits your needs

Comment: So I did this:`typedef float(sygnal::*funkcja)(float,float);
 funkcja ff;
 list<funkcja> lista;
 ff=&sygnal::Potegowanie;
 lista.push_back(ff);` But how do I then call it later? And can I pass arguments with the function to the list or is it impossible?

Comment: You have a list of [`pointer-to-member-function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pointer) pointers. You need an object instance of `sygnal` to call the member functions on, eg: `sygnal s; for (list<funkcja>::iterator iter = lista.begin(); iter != lista.end(); ++iter) { funkcja ff = *iter; float value1 = ...; float value2 = ...; float result = (s.*ff)(value1, value2); ... }`

Answer (score 0):

You might want to represent the blocks as classes. That way you can easily store the output of a function block inside the block itself, or if the block is more complex the entire input history. You could also store the output history of blocks inside themselves where you may be interested in it, e.g. to check the entire signal halfway through the chain.

It would also allow you to easily create a list (or, as in the example below, a vector) of base class pointers to instances of derived classes.

Something like:

```
class base {
public:
  struct param { float p, q; };
  virtual void input(param const & p) = 0;
  virtual param const & output() const = 0;
}

class amplify : public base {
public:
  amplify(float const factor_) : factor(factor_) { out.p = out.q = 0.0 }
  void input(param const & p) {
    out.p = p.p * amp;
    out.q = p.q * amp;
  }
  param const & output() const { return out; }
private:
  param out;
  float amp;
}

class system {
public:
  typedef std::vector<base *> blockchain;
  typedef std::vector<base::param> signal;
  void add_block(base * const block) { blocks.push_back(block); }
  void run(signal const & in, signal & out) {
    for(size_t iidx = 0; iidx < in.size(); ++iidx) {
      if(blocks.size() > 0) { blocks[0]->input(in[iidx]); }
      for(size_t bidx = 1; bidx < blocks.size(); ++bidx) {
        blocks[bidx]->input(blocks[bidx-1]->output());
      }
      if(blocks.size() > 0) { out.push_back(blocks[blocks.size()-1]->output(); }
    }
  }
private:
  blockchain blocks;
}
```